# Subspaces dimensions in $\mathbb{R}^7$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^7$  and $\dim U = \dim W =4$

then in $U \cap W$ there's a vector different then $0$.

I think that it's true, am I correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  If their intersection was $\{0\}$, then their sum $U+W$ would be a direct sum, so $\dim (U+W)$ would be equal to $8$, which is impossible, since it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^7$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since $\dim (U+W)=\dim U +\dim W - \dim (U\cap W)$.

In your case: $\dim (U+W)=8 - \dim (U\cap W)$, and note that $\dim (U+W) \leq 7$.